# How to Post in a WEB API RESTFULL random credit card number

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am very new to C# coding, or to coding at all, I am trying to create an API RESTFULL that when the user POST its email, it creates automatically a simples credit card number. I am at the very begging of the POST function.

// POST: api/Clientes

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> PostCliente(Cliente cliente)
    {
        _context.Clientes.Add(cliente);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetCliente", new { id = cliente.Id }, cliente);
        
    }
```

So my question is, what is the code line that wil generate a 16 number and register in the api thru POST?
thanks for the help in advance.

PART 2

Thanks for the solution, it partily worked. However, when i deploy it into Postman, even if I am able to register the ID - EMAIL - CREDIT CARD NUMBER (which is great, I am still geting an error message, the one below. Would you know how can I not get this message?

`System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)`

(The message is too long for me to post all here)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your question?

Comment: So you're asking how to generate a random 16-character string of numbers?  Or is there some issue in the API controller action that you're trying to allude to?  It's difficult to see specifically what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question. Basically i wanto to know how to generate and Post at the API.
When the user giver me the email, it regiser the email and also a random credit card number.

Comment: How you deploy API to postman?

Comment: Test it? @zolty13

Comment: Please show your postman request and your model code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a property "CreditCardNumber" in Cliente class, basically, you can write it in this way

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> PostCliente(Cliente cliente)
{
    //Begin
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int cardNumber1 = rnd.Next(4572, 4999);
    int cardNumber2 = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
    int cardNumber3 = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
    int cardNumber4 = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
    cliente.CreditCardNumber = $"{cardNumber1} {cardNumber2} {cardNumber3} {cardNumber4}";
    //End
    _context.Clientes.Add(cliente);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetCliente", new { id = cliente.Id }, cliente);
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tunjay for you reply, it helped me a lot.

Comment: However, when it deploy it into Postman, even if I am able to register the ID - EMAIL - CREDIT CARD NUMBER (which is great, I am still geting an error message, the one below.

Would you know how can I not get this message?

`System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)`

@Tunjay

Comment: Late answer, but lots of things can cause it, need to see the code